# PHPXMLRPC Blog post to Drupal with metaWeblog.newPost: Wrong number of method parameters

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I'm trying to post a simple text string to my drupal site. It needs to be done with metaWeblog.newPost because with blogger.newPost sets all the text as title. I've already tried that one.

I've got this thus far:

```
 require_once('xmlrpc-v1.174.inc');

$appkey     = "0001000";
$blogid     = "blog";

$username   = "xxxx";
$password   = "xxxx";
$text       = "testing";
$boolean    = "true";

$content['title'] = "Testen van metaWeblog.newPost";
$content['description'] = $text;

$oMessage = new xmlrpcmsg('metaWeblog.newPost');

$oMessage->addParam( new xmlrpcval( $blogid , 'string' ));
$oMessage->addParam( new xmlrpcval( $username , 'string' ));
$oMessage->addParam( new xmlrpcval( $password , 'string' ));
$oMessage->addParam( $content , 'struct' );
$oMessage->addParam( new xmlrpcval( $boolean , 'boolean' ));

$oClient = new xmlrpc_client("http://example.nl/drupal/xmlrpc.php");

$oClient->setDebug(0);

$oResponse = $oClient->send( $oMessage );

if ($oResponse->faultCode() ) {
    $xWebserviceOutput = $oResponse->faultString();
}
else
{
    $oValue = $oResponse->value();
    $xWebserviceOutput = $oValue->scalarval();
}

echo $xWebserviceOutput;
```

I'm have used this documentation:

http://www.sixapart.com/developers/xmlrpc/metaweblog_api/metaweblognewpost.html
http://expressionengine.com/wiki/How_to_add_an_entry_using_PHP_and_Metaweblog_API/
http://api.drupal.org/api/function/blogapi_metaweblog_new_post/6

The error it generates is the following:

```
Server error. Wrong number of method parameters.
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To which library does xmlrpc-v1.174.inc belong? Seem an odd version number for http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net . Also which version of drupal do you use?

Comment: Is it possible to add the the exact body that you're sending over to the question? That should help debug..

Comment: @VolkerK
xmlrpc-v1.174.inc is the latest version of phpxmlrpc. It's the version number they use in the lib itself.
I'm using v6 of Drupal.

@Evert
What do you mean Evert? The code I posted should be all there is needed to post something on Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
require_once('xmlrpc-v1.174.inc');

$client = new xmlrpc_client( "http://example.nl/drupal/xmlrpc.php" );
$f = new xmlrpcmsg("metaWeblog.newPost",
    array(
        new xmlrpcval( "blog", "string"), // BlogID (Ignored)
        new xmlrpcval( "xxxx", "string"), // User
        new xmlrpcval( "xxxx", "string"),    // Pass
        new xmlrpcval( // body
        array(
            "title" => new xmlrpcval("Testen van metaWeblog", "string"),

        ), "struct"),
        new xmlrpcval(true, "boolean") // publish
    )
);

$oResponse = $client->send($f);


for ($i = 0; $i < $f->getNumParams(); $i++) {
    $e = $f->getParam($i);
    echo $e->scalarval();
}

$xWebserviceOutput;

if ($oResponse->faultCode() ) {
    $xWebserviceOutput = $oResponse->faultString();
}
else
{
    $oValue = $oResponse->value();
    $xWebserviceOutput = $oValue->scalarval();
}

echo $xWebserviceOutput;
```